# Autosuggest with selenium and python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have below requirement to do the automation using selenium and python. Can someone please help me with the code:

1. Enter the exact query string in the search box
2. In the auto-suggest, the exact name is appearing as a suggestion.
3. Manually the way it works is, if I click the auto-suggested option, then the new webpage opens.

I am stuck in step3.

My code is:

```
search_query = 'enter search string'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get("about:blank")
driver.get("enter website name")
search_textbox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='txtCompanySearch']")   #XPATH can be found with developer tools in browsers
search_textbox.send_keys(search_query)
```

Comment: 1 - What is the error? 2 - Is the field well-loaded? A explicity wait may be necessary. (I can transform this comment in answer if that's is the problem)

Comment: Are you trying to navigate to the application?